# Choosing an operating point with SVM's, and categorical models in general

Tags: machine-learning, svm, categorical-data

So, I'm trying to classify data belonging to one of two classes. The classes are mutually exclusive, and every data point belongs to one or the other.

So I tried a few classifiers. In the case of the SVM, i get two outputs, the probability of belonging to category A, and the probability of belonging to category B. In this type of model, I believe the normal course of action is to do winner takes all.

That doesn't give me much flexibility in terms of choosing an operating point, based on my sensitivity/specificity requirements. With that in mind, I opted to use P(B) - P(A) as my score.

Intuitively, the difference makes sense to me. If the model is 100% sure that my data point is from category B, and 100% sure that it's not from category A, then i get a score of 1. In the reverse situation, I get a score of -1.

Since I did just make it up on a whim, however, I'm not sure that this is the best way to turn a categorical model into a binary decision. It does seem to work, and outperform the neural networks I've been training up. So I thought I'd ask. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all by operating point do you mean setting some threshold? .

Even though you are getting a better fit it doesn't necessarily mean its good. P(B)-P(A) seems fine in the case you mentioned. But what about when P(A) =0.7 and P(3)=0.4 ? . Its clear that the point belongs to Class A. By subtracting it will get classified in the wrong class. So my suggestion is to use the direct classification results.